# Assign different user for editing rows based on criteria in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to this forum as well as to the google spreadsheet, while using this spreadsheet and sharing this spreadsheet with different collaborators, i need the following help as:

**Data Available:**
In one sheet the name of the collaborators are given with there e-mail IDs, against the dealers code, e.g. In Col A: Dealership Code, Col B: Name of the Collaborator, Col C: e-mail ID of the collaborator

In another sheet2 the database of dealers are given, like Col A:Dealership Code, Col B: Name of  the collaborator, Col C: Status (a variable, which is to be edited by the Collaborator).

**Required:**

What is required in the Sheet2, only the collaborator against the dealership code can edit the status in Column C (after sharing of the spreadsheet), other rows of the spreadsheet remains protected, and the collaborator may not be able to change the status of other collaborator.

Comment: I have posted the same question on this link also:http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/how-do-i/desktop/m19f7gvcSz8

Answer (score 1):

I'll give the same answer as in the Docs forum : you cannot protect a single row or even a single sheet in a spreadsheet. I suppose you'll have to re-think your approach differently to get a working solution with the existing tools.
Why not, for example, have a non-shared spreadsheet for every collaborator that synchronizes some data with a common spreadsheet ? You would have the same functionality, wouldn't you ?